# how to validate $xmlDoc->load($xml);

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

this is my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
   <channel>
      <title>Title</title>
      <link>http://www.Mydomain.com</link>
      <description>Description</description>
      <managingEditor>managingEditor</managingEditor>
      <webMaster>webMaster</webMaster>
      <lastBuildDate>Sat, 19 Oct 2013 09:21:40 +0400</lastBuildDate>
      <generator>generator</generator>
      <item>
         <title>title</title>
         <link>link</link>
         <description>ATT&T</description>
         <author>author</author>
         <pubDate>25 Aug 2013 16:52:31 +0400</pubDate>
      </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

and i am reading like this:

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);
```

but i am getting this error:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::load(): EntityRef: expecting ';' in 
file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/readxml/rss.xml, line: 14 in
```

because of ' & ' ... in description Node

Please Advise

Comment: You are using the wrong term. This is not XML validation. You only have an invalid XML document, XML validation is the process to say whether or not a document is valid, not to make it valid. Instead you try to *recover* the invalid XML document when you load it, [set `DOMDocument::$recover` to true](http://php.net/class.domdocument#domdocument.props.recover). Also see [`libxml_use_internal_errors`](http://php.net/libxml_use_internal_errors) to control error handling when using `DOMDocument::load()`.

Comment: Instead of trying to parse invalid XML with an XML parser, use a liberal feed parser such as [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You want to alter your XML. To make sure you have no problems with the XML document, you should contain strings containing `&` of `<` or `>` in CDATA.

So your description should look like this

```
<description><![CDATA[ATT&T]]></description>
```

More details [here](http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/09/understanding-cdata-in-xml/)

UPDATE:

Since the OP posted he can't modify the XML.

Replace the `&` symbols with the `&amp;` entity:

```
$xml = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $xml);
```

The line above will replace -all- &'s with the `&amp;` entity.

Comment: ok but how i am reading from some websites, by calling their rss url , how can i modify it during : $xmlDoc->load($xml);

Comment: I think this is the point where you actually start learning what you are doing.. How about reading the documentation about DOMdocument (or, a hint, try SimpleXml)

Comment: yes i am new in DOMdocument, but i finished all script , only sometimes for some rss url i have this problem , i can validate the schema after load, but on xml->load , i am getting error

Comment: no this is not a write way, what i did is this: libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
            $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
            if($xmlDoc->load($RSSURL->URL))
            {...}else{echo 'not valis xml comtent';

Comment: You are absolutely right ofcourse. You should not fix the errors, you should just disable them all together (</sarcasm>). I also suggest putting '@' in front of all your php commands so those don't bother you with errors either. You do realize that will surpress missing tags, invalid attributes etc aswell right?

Answer (score 0):

Replace ATT&T with ATT&amp;T as unescaped ampersands aren't allowed in XML.

Comment: ATT&amp;T still contains an unescaped ampersand..

Comment: @DamienOvereem `&amp;` is valid entity, not just ampersand.

Comment: ok but how i am reading from some websites, by calling their rss url , how can i modify it during : $xmlDoc->load($xml);

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE:

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
if($xmlDoc->load($RSSURL->URL))
{

}else{
     echo 'XML file is not valid structure';
}
```